# Sum two values separated by a comma in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where a few columns have two values separated by a comma kind of like this:

```
x<-c("a", "b", "c")
y<-c("1", "2", "3,4")
z<-c("3", "4", "1,2")
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)
```

Is there a way I can find all these cells with two values in a data frame and replace them with their sum using r? So I would like to end up with something like this:

```
x<-c("a", "b", "c")
y<-c("1", "2", "7")
z<-c("3", "4", "3")
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use `separate_rows` on 'y', 'z' column to split at the delimiter `,`, expand the rows, grouped by 'x' column, get the `sum` of all other columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   separate_rows(y, z, convert = TRUE) %>%
   group_by(x) %>% 
   summarise_all(sum)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  x         y     z
#  <fct> <int> <int>
#1 a         1     3
#2 b         2     4
#3 c         7     3
```

Comment: I tried this with my dataset, however I get the error message "Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: invalid 'type' (character) of argument." I tried changing to numeric, but then all of the entries that have a comma get automatically changed to NAs. Is there a different type I should use?

Comment: @Mary Can you create your dataset as `character` class (though it is working fine for me) `df<-data.frame(x,y,z, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. Iss this error from the same example?

Answer (score 0):

For each column we use `gsubfn` to match digits, comma, digits passing the two sets of digits to the function expressed in formula notation. The output of the function replaces the input.

```
library(gsubfn)

repl <- function(x) gsubfn("(\\d+),(\\d+)", ~ as.numeric(x) + as.numeric(y), paste(x))
replace(df, TRUE, lapply(df, repl))
```

giving:

```
  x y z
1 a 1 3
2 b 2 4
3 c 7 3
```